# What is the colour which is suited to the a9eafe colour?

Tags: graphics, dialog

I am developping a mobile phone application , and I display a dialog box when there are information to show to the user. The background colour of the dialog box is `a9eafe` in hexadecimal form.

I want to add a title bar to the dialog box and I do not know which colour should I set to that title bar so that the `a9eafe` background colour is well suited to that colour.

So what colour is good for the title bar to be combined with the background colour `a9eafe` so that the dialog box is user-friendly ?

PS : I want the colour to be expressed also in hexadecimal form because the editor I am using only recognizes hexadecimal colour.

Comment: how about `FF6A00`? kind of difficult to give an answer to this one, though, because it is based solely on personal opinion...

Comment: @Chips_100 The FF6A00 is like an orange colour. I think it does not really good with the `a9eafe`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there are a lot of options. The best thing you could do would be to try an online palette generator. You could try
http://colorschemedesigner.com/